# Why MatDialog is not showing?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here is my login component:

```
 constructor(private router: Router, private dialog: MatDialog) { }
   login() : void {

      if(login_is_correct)
      {
        this.router.navigate(["home"]);
      }
      else
      {
          let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(IncorrectLoginInfoComponent, {
  data: { name: 'someName', title: 'Invalid credentials' },
});
      }
    });

  }
```

The dialog `IncorrectLoginInfoComponent`:

```
    export class IncorrectLoginInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<IncorrectLoginInfoComponent>) { }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close('Dialog has been closed!');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Template:

```
    <h2 mat-dialog-title>{{ data.title }}</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>passed in by {{ data.name }} Are you sure?</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Non</button>
  <!-- The mat-dialog-close directive optionally accepts a value as a result for the dialog. -->
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Oui</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

I also added the following from [Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) in `app.module.ts`:

```
     providers: [
  {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: false}}
  ],
   entryComponents: [
    IncorrectLoginInfoComponent
  ]
```

When I click login I don't see any dialog and the project compiled successfully!!

What is missing in this configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: What error shows up in your developer tools console?

Comment: Plase post your complete module code.

Comment: If you provide width and height, does that work? `{ width: '40%', height:'50%',
  data: { name: 'someName', title: 'Invalid credentials' },
}`

Comment: @TiagoSilva, and others, thank you all for your time, it is working!! the backend API was not "Port Already in Use" when I fixed that it is good, thanks,I should delete this maybe and apologyze.Thanks.